# Conceptualization of 'по'

Tags: значения

I am having a hard time sometimes conceptualizing 'по' when I come across it in my reading.

Take for example a sentence from Bulgakov: 'Трудно сказать, что именно подвело Ивана Николаевича – изобразительная ли сила его таланта или полное незнакомство с вопросом, по которому он писал...'

When I read this sentence, I view the 'по' as 'along' or 'according to,' but doesn't seem to feel right in this context (writing along or according to a question).

If I were to construct a sentence like this myself (from English into Russian)-- 'whether it was the descriptive power of his talent or complete unfamiliarity with the question he was writing about...' I would maybe write it as 'незнакомство с вопросом, над котором он писал' или 'о том, что он писал', but not using 'по.'

To reiterate, what should I know about 'по' so I am in a better position to understand what I am reading or hearing and how can I personally better incorporate it in my speech and writing? I know this is a broad and more theoretical question, but comments and insights are very much appreciated.

Comment: [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/по](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE) see item 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**По** is a very versatile preposition with a lot of abstract meanings that one doesn't intuitively associate with its perceived "literal" meaning of moving over a surface. It may perhaps be easier to consider its individual usages separately, almost as if it were different prepositions.

I don't have sources for this but from what I can tell by looking at the bigger picture of Slavic languages, the original literal meaning of **по** was most likely "after", or something similar ultimately referring to the action of *following*. In the particular case of Russian, what I think happened was that its meaning of "following" a path, trail, etc. branched off into a more general meaning of moving over any surface, not necessarily one that suggests a direction; that meaning eventually superseded the original one, but many of the more abstract usages of **по** still have "following", rather than "surface", as their underlying metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the preposition "**по** (вопросу)" in your example is close to that of '**on**' in the expression 'on that subject' ('lack of knowledge about the subject he was writing **on**').